# How to stretch an svg on android 4.4.x in the standard browser?

Tags: android, browser, svg, stretch

I am trying to stretch an svg on android 4.4.x in the standard browser.
It works above android 4.0 but stopped on 4.4.x

I used the following code which does not work any more on 4.4.x

```
<img src="..." style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
```

and

```
background-image: url('...');
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

I can even use pixels and set in to width: 10px and height: 1000px.

It will always preserve its aspect ratio and won't stretch further.

However the strange thing is that the exact same thing DOES still work with png/jpg images.
For some reason it obviously just stopped working for svgs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an SVG to be stretched to fill the size given, make sure it has a `viewBox` attribute.

```
<svg ... viewBox="<appropriate values here>" ... >
```

Comment: Thank you Paul LeBeau. Yes is have noticed that the newest chrome does need it. In my case preserveAspectRatio="none" in the svg tag was enough :)